# Push to array a key name taken from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array:

```
var pages = new Array();
```

I want to push my pages data to this array like this:

```
$('li.page').each(function () {
        var datatype = $(this).attr('data-type');
        var info = $(this).attr('data-info');
        pages_order.push({datatype:info});
    });
```

but this code doesn't replace `datatype` as variable, just puts datatype string as a key.
How do I make it place there actual string value as a key name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Array of Key/Value Pairs Uses Literal Variable Name for Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491828/javascript-array-of-key-value-pairs-uses-literal-variable-name-for-key)

Answer (score 10):

I finally saw what you were trying to do:

```
var pages = new Array();
$('li.page').each(function () {
    var datatype = $(this).attr('data-type');
    var info = $(this).attr('data-info');
    var temp = {};
    temp[datatype] = info;
    pages_order.push(temp);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li.page').each(function () {

    //get type and info, then setup an object to push onto the array
    var datatype = $(this).attr('data-type'),
        info = $(this).attr('data-info'),
        obj  = {};

    //now set the index and the value for the object
    obj[datatype] = info;
    pages_order.push(obj);
});
```

Notice that you can put a comma between variable declarations rather than reusing the `var` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to store two pieces of information for each page. You can do that by pushing an array instead of an object:

```
pages_order.push([datatype, info]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `datatype` in a context where it will be evaluated.

Like so.

```
var pages = [];
$('li.page').each(function () {
    var datatype = $(this).attr('data-type'),
        info = $(this).attr('data-info'),
        record = {};
    record[datatype] = info;
    pages_order.push(record);
});
```

You only need one `var` it can be followed by multiple assignments that are separated by `,`.

No need to use `new Array` just use the array literal `[]`

Answer (score 0):

You may add below single line to push value with key:

```
pages_order.yourkey = value;
```