# JavaScript Array of Key/Value Pairs Uses Literal Variable Name for Key

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an array of key/value pairs by using the `push` method, but getting unexpected results.

`console.log` prints this:

> books: [{"bookTitle":"Mark Twain"}]

Whereas I would expect this:

> books: [{"Tom Sawyer" : "Mark Twain"}]

Here's the code:

```
var books = [];
var bookTitle = "Tom Sawyer";
var author = "Mark Twain";

books.push({bookTitle : author})

console.log("books: %s", JSON.stringify(books))
```

I've tried `books.bookTitle = author` and `books[bookTitle] = author`, but the result is the same.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Notice that `books` is an array, the bracket notation would have worked if you had called it on the single book (`books[0]`)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) is the correct way to use a dynamic key name:

```
books[bookTitle] = author
```

However, you need to use an intermediate object:

```
var books = [];
var bookTitle = "Tom Sawyer";
var author = "Mark Twain";
var foo = {};
foo[bookTitle] = author;

books.push(foo);

console.log("books: %s", JSON.stringify(books))
```

Comment: Is there a good justification for why jscript was designed this way?  I find that design aggravating.

Answer (score 15):

In modern Javascript (ES2015+), you can use [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) which modifies your example code in one slight way-- square brackets are wrapped around the key name to signify it should be computed *before* assignment:

```
var books = [];
var bookTitle = "Tom Sawyer";
var author = "Mark Twain";

books.push({[bookTitle] : author})
```

... which correctly yields:

> [ { 'Tom Sawyer': 'Mark Twain' } ]

This is similar to Matt Ball's original answer, but avoids the verbosity of using temporary variables.

Comment: I know it's been awhile...I'm unable to access a value in the resulting array using this code. let a = books["Tom Sawyer"] comes back as undefined.

Comment: @RobertM., this is an array, so you'd first need to index it: books[0]['Tom Sawyer']